# Should I create a new CSS file for each HTML page if I am using CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there a way to use only 1 CSS file whilst using CSS grid to position unique content for multiple different web pages? Or do I have to create a new CSS file for each web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a grid rule written in a CSS class, e.g. `.myGridRule`, and store it in the `style.css`, you can import that file on each page you needed and apply that class to elements you want.